# Property 'component' does not exist on type

Tags: react-router

Why do I get this error when I declare a "component" property in "Route";

Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)'.

````
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import './App.css'
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage'

function App() {
  return(
    <div>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" component={HomePage}/>
    </Routes>
    </div>
  )
} ``` The problem might be; because I dont use 'exact path="/"' that might also give an error
````

Comment: react-router just got an update that breaks all old code again. Perhaps you accidentally got the latest react-router with an old tutorial?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

With the upgrade of react-router-dom to version 6.0, certain properties have changed. The syntax you are using will work fine for version 5.0. To update to v6, make this change to your code:

```
<Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
```

Comment: Oh lord, I was searching for a solution for hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Version 6 of the router changed the way to create these kinds of routes - https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

nanoTitan got the right answer with:

```
<Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
```

Regarding `exact` - I do not think you need to worry about this any more. If you have a route like `/` and another route like `/about` version 6 is smart enough to route to about.  Apparently, even if you have routes like `/user/:uuid` and `/user/new` - navigating to `/user/new` will be understood as the new page.

I also found that tutorials and the like are all about version 5, it is a confusing environment to learn in.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by simply typing this instead;

```
<Route path="/">{HomePage}</Route>
```

And it worked

Answer (score -4):

Just switch version of react-router-dom to "^5.1.2", and @types/react-router-dom: to "^5.1.3"

Comment: This is unhelpful and a poor solution moving forward